# Track ETL_LOAD Summery

Tags: mapping, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

how can we implement the following audit trail scenario using Informatica power center

**table1 batch table**

```
batch_id,
app_name,
start_datetime,
end_datetime,
status
```

(it should contain the info about complete load i.e when does the first workflow start and when does it end)

**Table2 Task table**

```
batch_id,
task_id,
task_nm(wk_name),
src_table_nm,
tgt_tbl_nm,
count_src_rows,
count_tgt_rows(after loading is done),
task_start_tm(wf_start_time),
task_end_tm(wf_end_time)
```

the relation between Batch and task table should be 1 to many

Thank you

Comment: It probably wouldn't be possible to provide a solution to your requirement. You have to try implementing it first yourself, and if you face any specific issue, ask StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

All the tasks performed in informatica is stored in a metadata tables. You ca verify the below blog to get the detals.

http://www.etltechblog.com/2012/01/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html